# Proof that Lebesgue Measure is Probability Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the field $\beta_0$ which contains all the finite disjoint unions of intervals within $(0,1]$. For example, the generic element can be expressed as $A_k=\cup_{i=1}^nI_i$ where the $I_i$'s are disjoint intervals. My textbook offers a proof that Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is countably additive over the field $\beta_0$, and I believe the proof uses an unjustified assumption.

In the proof, it is written: "Suppose that $A=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$, where the $A_i$'s are disjoint, and $A$ and the $A_i$'s are $\beta_0$-sets."

My question: how do we know that $A$ is a $\beta_0$-set? Although $\beta_0$ is a field, it is not a $\sigma$-field.

Edit: Problem solved in the comments.

Comment: This is the **definition** of "countably additive" for a field.  Only elements of the field can appear in $A=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$.

Comment: @GEdgar Could you elaborate? I don't understand how "countably additive" can be a characteristic of a field. It would need to be a characteristic of set function in this case.

Comment: it is perhaps assumed that $A$ is an element of the field: You want to prove that the measure is countably additive over this field, so from the beginning all sets considered are assumed to belong to the field. Just a guess (I would think this is what @GEdgar meant too).

Comment: Where does this come from?  Look in the preceding section of the book to find the definitions used.